# ROR: HTML input button not posting to controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, submit-button

I have very simple HTML (password.html.erb):

```
<h1>Enter business password to enter:</h1>

<input type="text" id="password" name="enter password"/>
<input type="submit" method="post" name="Submit"/>
```

This should, on clicking of submit, trigger an action in my controller called 'check':

```
def check
    @entered = params['password']
    if @entered == current_customer.business.manager_password_digest
      puts("success!")
      redirect to '/manage'
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'Invalid password'
      render 'password'
    end
  end
```

Here is my route:

```
get '/password' => 'pages#password'
  post '/password' => 'pages#check'
```

But when I click submit, nothing happens. Is it not possible to use an input in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using rails helpers and you need to specify the path where you want to post the data:

```
<h1>Enter business password to enter:</h1>
<%= form_tag("/password") do  %>
 <%= text_field_tag :password %>
 <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told your button to execute which action on click. for this you should use action for the submit button.

```
  <h1>Enter business password to enter:</h1>
  <input type="text" id="password" name="enter password"/>
  <input type="submit" method="post" name="Submit"/ action = '/password'>
```